# Call discord bot function from django

Tags: python, django, discord.py

I'm using Django for my backend. I would like to allow my website to call discord bot functions.

A simplified example:

When a user goes to my index page a bot will send "Hello world" from discordscript.py and I want to run it from views.py:

```
async def hello(): 
    await ExampleChannel.send("Hello word!")
```

Is there any way to call these kinds of bot functions from views.py or how can I put some discord bot code directly into views.py?

Answer (score 0):

you can use discord webhooks:

- first, see this video tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=hS_981bBG-8)
- then use [python-discord-webhook](https://github.com/lovvskillz/python-discord-webhook)